# Quick Assembly of sparse matrix

Tags: matlab, sparse-matrix

I have indices

```
I = [nGrid x 9] matrix % mesh on fine grid (9 point rectangle)
J = [nGrid x 4] matrix % mesh on coarse grid (4 point rectangle)
```

Here, `nGrid` is large number depending on the mesh (e.g. 1.e05)

Then I want to do like

```
R_ref = [4 x 9] matrix % reference restriction matrix from fine to coarse
P_ref = [9 x 4] matrix % reference prolongation matrix from coarse to fine

R = sparse(size) % n_Coarse x n_Fine
P = sparse(size) % n_Fine x n_Coarse
for k = 1 : nGrid % number of elements on coarse grid
    R(I(k,:),J(k,:)) = R_ref;
    P(J(k,:),I(k,:)) = P_ref;
end
```

`size` is predetermined number.

Note that even if there is same index in `(I,J)`, I do not want to accumulate. I just want to put stencils `Rref` and `Pref` at each indices respectively.

I know that this is very slow due to the data structure of sparse.

Usually, I use

```
sparse(row,col,entry,n_row,n_col)
```

I can use this by manipulate `I`, `J`, `R_ref`, `P_ref` by `bsxfun` and `repmat`.

However, this cannot be done because of the accumulation of `sparse` function

(if there exists `(i,j)` such that `[row(i),col(i)]==[row(j),col(j)]`, then `R(row(i),row(j)) = entry(i)+entry(j)`)

Is there any suggestion for this kind of assembly procedure?

## Sample code

```
%% INPUTS
% N and M could be much larger
N = 2^5+1; % number of fine grid in x direction
M = 2^5+1; % number of fine grid in y direction


% [nOx * nOy] == nGrid
nOx = floor((M)/2)+1; % number of coarse grid on x direction
nOy = floor((N)/2)+1; % number of coarse grid on y direction

Rref = [4     4    -1     4    -2     0    -1     0     0
    -1    -1    -2     4     4     4    -1     4     4
    -1    -1     4    -2     4    -2     4     4    -1
    0     4     4     0     0     4    -1    -2    -1]/8;

Pref = [2     1     0     1     0     0     0     0     0
    0     0     0     1     1     1     0     1     2
    0     0     1     0     1     0     2     1     0
    0     2     1     0     0     1     0     0     0]'/2;


%% INDEX GENERATION
tri_ref = reshape(bsxfun(@plus,[0,1,2]',[0,N,2*N]),[],1)';
TRI_ref = reshape(bsxfun(@plus,[0,1]',[0,nOy]),[],1)';
I = reshape(bsxfun(@plus,(1:2:N-2)',0:2*N:(M-2)*N),[],1);
J = reshape(bsxfun(@plus,(1:nOy-1)',0:nOy:(nOx-2)*nOy),[],1);
I = bsxfun(@plus,I,tri_ref);
J = bsxfun(@plus,J,TRI_ref);


%% THIS PART IS WHAT I WANT TO CHANGE
R = sparse(nOx*nOy,N*M);
P = R';
    for k = 1 : size(I,1)
    R(J(k,:),I(k,:)) = Rref;
    P(I(k,:),J(k,:)) = Pref;
end
```